# Sublime Text 3 vertical paste on large number of lines

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

This is a follow-up question for this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/861724/319136). While working with vertical selection/pasting this answere works only for the destination pasting area should be selected with <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>+for same number of lines.

To my situation it is unrealistic while pasting large number of lines. In Notepad++ this is natural since I don't need to match the number of lines in the destination area. Just placing the cursor in starting point is enough.

Any clues on how this situation to be handled for Sublime Text 3?